# Different icon positions for main menu among stackexchange.com and any other site

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com, icons

Icons (and find a community bar) are slightly shifted to the top (i.e. not centered on community name) in the main menu for [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/):

> [image: se.com]

Compare it with MSE:

> [image: mse]