# Find community text partially obscured in the edit box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, firefox

The current community top bar menu contains an edit named "Find a SE community". The text in this edit is partially obscured on the top and on the bottom:

> [image: Find a SE community]

I'm using FF 58.0.2.

Comment: Repro-ed on FF, no repro on Chrome or Edge. In IE11 the text is slightly offset from the top but not cut-off

Comment: Repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 58.0.2

Comment: Not reproducible on Windows 7 Professional, Firefox 59.0b11 (64-bit)

Comment: @Arulkumar beta isn’t supported by SO :-D

Comment: Probably bug in Firefox itself, so hopefully it will be fixed with some new release soon. (6-8 years?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard in this case it should be renamed to fireSOx.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't happen on stackexchange.com

Comment: @Glorfindel SE.com topbar differs from the other sites. For instance here is [one difference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303347/339911).

Comment: @Glorfindel probably doesn't happen in Area 51 too, which has the old version of the top bar. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is no more exists in the recent Firefox version.

I have verified in the **FF 59.0 (64-bit)**.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: No more alignment issue]

Comment: Confirmed fixed in 59.0.

Comment: @JarrodDixon how about [supporting last two versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307908/339911)? :)

Comment: I'm using the __latest__ Firefox __ESR__ version and the bug is verifiable: [Search string for StackExchange Sites is clipped on Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308432/358130)